# Explaining an HTTP "GET" request

Tags: php, jquery, post, get, http-get

I have many times successfully implemented HTTP "POST" requests in my projects, more importantly because i could understand how the request worked in my code.

Now i need to make a "GET" request , but i am a bit confused on how i can accomplish it.

I have an html-jQuery page , that when launched sends an *"id"* (POST request) to my PHP server. Then , i need my PHP server , to look in the database in which events this *"id"* is subscribed to and return the events.

So i need to make a "GET" request , where i send as parameter the *"id"* and i get back a json file with the events. However how this PHP file would look like? I mean , i can write a php script that accepts an *"id"* as input ,makes the right SQL queries to look for the events and create a json file with them. But how do i return it to my html-jquery page though?

Or should the "GET" request target only XML/JSON files? The way i see what i described till now is that my jquery makes a POST request to my server with the id and the server makes a POST request to my web page with the events. Is not exactly a "GET" ...

Comment: I think you need to read up on http traffic. You get or post to the server, the server responds. http://www.diffen.com/difference/Get_vs_Post
`$_REQUEST['id'];` vs `$_GET['id'];` vs `$_POST['id'];`

Comment: so in the end, what i need to so is 2 "post" requests? One from my web page to the server and one back?

Comment: There is no get or post action on the server side. `echo $somevar` will send the result back in all cases - if you need to get data from yet another server WHILE you are on the server, you need to get/post using CURL

Comment: PERFECT! This echo was exactly what i was looking for. Now i understand how on earth works. The answer from @rawphl helped me understand. Thank you a lot !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do what you want.

With JQuery and Ajax it would look like this:

```
$.get("yourpage.php", {id: 5}, function(jsonResult){

 // do whatever with the json result from the server

});
```

in "yourpage.php"

```
$id = $_GET["id"];
//do database query etc


$result = array("yourdata" => "yourvalue")

echo json_encode($result);
```

Have a look at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/ or http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

And you should learn about the basics of http requests / responses. It seems like you don't really know what you are doing.

Comment: aaah!! Exactly what i was looking for was you "echo" command. If i understand well , this echo is what will be returned to my web page? Right? So there i can return from a simple "ok 200" string , to a json file with my data. Correct?

Comment: Yes, you can return different kinds of data with echo. If you want to return json, you must either transform an array to json as I did in the example or parse the json from a file.

Comment: Could you show me exactly how i could get the response from a post ? i mean in the jQuery part , how would it look like. i use smth like:$.ajax({type: "POST", url: "http://...",data: data
    }).success(function(response){}
but it doesnt seem to work